# conditions inside a target in makefile along with commands

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

I need my make to work in the following scenarios. At least one among flag_a or flag_b is to be set while doing make. There is possibility for flag_c also in future.
make flag_a=true
or
make flag_b=true
or
make flag_a=true flag_b=true

Cleanup is simple "make clean". It should clean everything irrespective of which flag was set during make.

In my makefile, I want to something like set a variable when a flag is set and finally add the variables. If the sum of variables is 0, that means no flag was set in make. I want to throw an error and terminate make in this case.
My makefile is something like the following.

1 FLAG_A_SET=0

2 FLAG_B_SET=0

3 all:

4 ifdef flag_a

5 FLAG_A_SET=1

6 endif

7 ifdef flag_b

8 FLAG_B_SET=1

9 endif

10 FLAGS_SUM=$(shell echo $(expr "$(FLAG_A_SET)" + "$(FLAG_B_SET)"))

11 ifeq ($(FLAGS_SUM), 0)

12 tab $(error You must specify at least one among flag_a and flag_b)

13 else

14 tab make -C files

15 endif

Then I am getting error "commands commence before first target" at line 14. 
Also I am doubtful about statement in line 10. Is the expression correct?
~

Answer (score 0):

Yikes.  You give no reason for wanting to do this in such a complex way.  If you really just want to know if one or more of a set of variables has any value, you can to it much more easily:

```
ifeq ($(flag_a)$(flag_b),)
  $(info no flag is set)
else
  $(info one or more flags are set)
endif
```

Basically, you expand all the flags and see if the result is equal to the empty string or not.

*ETA*

If you want to avoid this check when running `clean` you can look at the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` variable to see what command line goals were provided and skip this test if it was `clean`:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
  ifeq ($(flag_a)$(flag_b),)
    $(info no flag is set)
  else
    $(info one or more flags are set)
  endif
endif
```

You could combine this into a single test using `filter-out` but it'd probably be more confusing than it's worth.

Comment: Hi MadScientist, that solves one of my problem. My logic for sum of flags is no longer required. Now my file is like following   1 all: $(BUILDDIRS)
  2 (BUILDDIRS): 
  3 ifeq ($(flag_a)$(flag_b),)
  4   $(error no flag is set)
  5 else
  6 tab$(MAKE) -C files
  7 endif. Then there is another section for clean. Now when I am doing make clean, I am getting error "*** no flag is set.  Stop".

Comment: Thanks MadScientist. Now all my issues are resolved.